# Setting a Bitmap to a ImageView

Tags: android

I have downloaded a Bitmap from a WebService, and set it to an ImageView. The ImageView has a set height of 120dip and a width set to FILL_PARENT, so it fills the complete width of the screen. Now i want to stretch the Bitmap to fit the width of the ImageView, but the if the height of the Bitmap is greater then the height of the ImageView, i want the remainder of the image to flow off the top and bottom of the ImageView. So in way, like i have a frame infront of the image and the only portion of the image visible is the contents of the frame. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Android Developers on ImageView [ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are interested in the [scale_type enum](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html). Use `CENTER_CROP`.

Here is complete example:

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
               android:layout_height="120dp"  
               android:layout_gravity="center"  
               android:src="@drawable/eureka"  
               android:scaleType="centerCrop">  
</ImageView>
```

Here is also a [cool visualization](http://etcodehome.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html) of all possible options for `ImageView`.

Comment: But how do i make sure it fits the width of the ImageView. I only want the Image to be cropped from the top and bottom ?

Comment: @BadLuckBrian The way `cetnerCrop` works is that the image is scaled until both sides at least fit in the selected dimensions. If your image width and height ratio is of the expected kind (that is when scaled, the width fits perfectly while the image pops out vertically) your image will be automatically situated as you desire.